# Firefox JSON viewer in iframe

Tags: javascript, json, firefox

Is it possible to use the [Firefox JSON viewer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/JSON_viewer) in an iframe? I tried to put a data-uri in an iframe but it just shows the contents as string. If I use "Open frame in new tab" the viewer is opened correctly.

```html
<iframe src="data:application/json;base64,eyJmb28iOnsic3BhbSI6ImhhbSJ9LCJiYXIiOlsxLDIsM119"></iframe>
```

I would like to use it as a debugging feature to show state of a data model variable, currently I use Angular `<pre ng-bind="$ctrl.foo|json:2"></pre>` a lot but it would be neat if it could be rendered using JSON viewer (at least in Firefox).

Comment: There are several different json-tree modules you can use

Comment: @charlietfl I'm using the Firefox builtin because I'd like to avoid pulling external dependencies when I just want to debug something temporary.

Comment: @ext did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @AndréPletschette Sorry no, didn't find a native solution. There are third-party tools but I preferred to not pull any more dependencies and went with only pretty-printed JSON. Still interested in a solution, will update with an answer if I do find any.

Comment: This seems to be deliberate: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1384572